# Wemos D1 mini and JSN-SR04T-2.0: Type of power supply affects the sensor readings

Tags: esp8266, power

Pretty similar to what is described [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67102/power-supply-affecting-sensor-readings-esp8266-and-jsn-sr04t-2-0#) I have the strange problem that my sensor readings are affected by the type of power supply I use.

Whenever I connect my D1 mini through USB with laptop everything works fine. The readings make sense and are quite accurate.
But as soon as I disconnect it from the laptop and use a USB power supply (I tested different ones) the readings do not make sense anymore.

I also tried to apply the sketch to a NodeMCU board. The results are the same. So I assume it has something to do with either the sensor or the ESP 12E.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you powering the sensor?

Comment: The sensor is powered by the 3.3V output of the Wemos/NodeMCU Board. But I also tested it with the 5V output. Always with the same results.

Comment: I'll bet your laptop's charger has 3 prongs that plug into the wall, but your USB power supplies only have 2 prongs. If so, try grounding to earth.

Comment: Easier said than done in this case :) But I'll try. Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Try a different supply or computer, it sounds like that one has a lot of ripple and or noise on it.  Not all USB power supplies are clean and some do not have much filtering.